# Trying to take data from a combo box with a foreign key and update the database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to update my SQL database with the code provided, I am basically trying to take a select statement to bring back just the INTGenderID based on a combo box and make it equal to a string then convert that to an integer when I do my update back into my database. If you need more info let me know. The main table is TGolfers and the parent table is TGenders.

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of code. Code is text so post it as text, formatted as code. We can't copy and paste code form pictures if we want to run it for ourselves or quote a specific line back to you. If you'd like us to volunteer our time to help you, you need to take the time to help us do so, which also means taking the tour you refused when prompted and reading more in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question.

Comment: Apart from that, don't build SQL code like that. Learn to use parameters in ADO.NET to protect yourself from numerous issues. There's also no need to build any `String` in lines like that, given that VB supports multiline string literals in recent versions and XML literals before that.

Comment: Also, it's goo d that you showed us where the error occurs but it's bad that you haven't provided the error message. That message is a diagnostic tool and you want us to do the diagnosis. The next step should be obvious.

Comment: If you want to concatenate `Strings` then use the concatenation operator (`&`), not the addition operator (`+`). They amount to the same thing in many situations but not all. Use the appropriate operator for the task you're performing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the question. Let's assume that you have a database table named `Thing` and that has columns `ThingId` and `Name`. You would generally query the database to populate a `DataTable` and then bind that to your `ComboBox`, e.g.

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString),
      command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ThingId, Name FROM Thing", connection)
    connection.Open()

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        table.Load(reader)
    End Using
End Using

With thingComboBox
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "ThingId"
    .DataSource = table
End With
```

The user will now see a list of `Name` values in the `ComboBox` and, when they select one, you can get the corresponding `ThingId` from the `SelectedValue` property, e.g.

```vb
Dim thingId = CInt(thingComboBox.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: And I just explained to you how to do that! In the example I provided, `ThingId` is the foreign key value and you get it from the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox`. If you populate the control properly, i.e. as I have demonstrated, then you can get the foreign key value easily, i.e. as I have demonstrated. If you are starting out by displaying an existing record then you assign the existing foreign key value to the `SelectedValue` in the first place to display the corresponding text for the existing related record. Just do what I did and change the names and you have your solution.

Comment: Lol this worked, I just put the selected value into the update string, TY Very Much. I have been struggling with this all day! Since I already had the combo loaded, I did not know I could reference it.